# flushing iptables causes kernel to hang

Tags: iptables, kernel, watchdog

On a hypervisor host I have a scripts which uses `iptables` to setup all the firewall rules for allowing and passing connections across various fabrics and VMs.

At the top of the script, I flush the tables:

```
iptables -t filter -F
```

Recently, this has been causing the kernel to hang and start throwing *abrt* messages:

```
Message from syslogd@node09 at July 5 14:09:52 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#10 stuck for 23s! [iptables:23172]
```

This message is printed multiple times with different core numbers, and only appears after seemingly minutes, not 23s.

---

Why would iptables be causing the kernel to hang like this?

Comment: It's been years since I've seen that. I'm about 90% sure it's a kernel bug that was fixed quite some time ago. Are you sure your system is up to date?

Comment: Hmm, I guess my kernel version is older - `3.10.0` - will be whatever was on the install media for Centos7.7. I can try updating the kernel.

Comment: The system appears much more happy after upgrading the kernel.